# Sync point of SQL Server backup

Tags: sql-server

What is the sync point of a Sql Server backup? If I have a full backup that runs from 20:12 to 20:38, when I restore the backup is it restoring to the state at 20:12? 20:38? Some other point?

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a full backup that runs from 20:12 to 20:38, when I restore the backup is it restoring to the state at 20:12? 20:38? Some other point?

To start, a full backup cannot be used to do point in time restores. If the backup finished at 20:38 and you restore it, it will restore all committed data uptill 20:38 and will rollback all uncommitted data uptill 20:38. For details about SQL Server full backup read technet article [Understanding SQL Server backups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx#id0980008). of course a full backup restores complete SQL Server database and to make sure restored database is consistent it also backups up few amount of transaction log so that when restored it can bring database to consistent point.